# What is the significance of Barbie contemplating death in the movie?

Tags: barbie

In *Barbie* (2023), we see a unique moment. Margot Robbie, as Barbie­, deals with mortality. This is different from the norm. Usually, Barbie is shown as carefree­ and perfect.

The idea of mortality makes us wonder. Why add such a dee­p idea? What does it mean for the film? It changes how we view Barbie­. It gives her story more depth.

Why does she choose this path for the narrative? How does it add to the film's view of Barbie?

Comment: *It changes how we view Barbie­. It gives her story more depth*, that sounds like an answer right there...

Comment: *"Math class is tough!"* - dude from marketing in 1992 wanted their soul back? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOKhRVSriB0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It is a significant and poignant moment as well as being a hilarious non-sequitur…

#### …and it is only a non-sequitur until the source/inspiration for the sentiments is revealed.

> “Usually, Barbie is shown as carefree­ and perfect.”

So having Barbie contemplate death would be a funny joke? I thought it was hilarious!

> “It changes how we view Barbie­. It gives her story more depth.”

You said it right there! That is the reason.

Also, within the logic of the film we discover…

> “Now, as an adult, Gloria has been trying and failing to connect with her teenage daughter. **In her sadness, she revisits her comfort toy, and accidentally imbues the doll with her darkest thoughts, causing Barbie to “malfunction”—her arched feet go flat, and she starts thinking about death.**” — Taken from “The Surprising Key to Understanding the Barbie Film” by Shirley Li from [*The Atlantic*](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2023/07/barbie-movie-america-ferrera/674781/); July 21, 2023.

As for the significance in the film itself, the death thoughts are funny on their own but when connected to that “real world” character’s own thoughts/actions it connects the “real world” to the “Barbie world” in a very profound and poignant way.